# Adding custom flag to CAT command in MINIX

Tags: c, minix

I am trying to modify `cat` command in MINIX 3.2.1, and I am having some problems with it. I want to add `-H` flag, so that when it is used, file name is printed before its contents. I have added some code in cat.c (referring to original lines' numbers):

Line 64 (`Hflag` variable):

```
int Hflag, bflag, eflag, fflag, lflag, nflag, sflag, tflag, vflag;
```

Line 85 ('H' case):

```
        case 'H':
            Hflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
```

Line 130 (Hflag parameter):

```
if (Hflag || bflag || eflag || nflag || sflag || tflag || vflag)
```

Line 142 (added `fprintf` to ensure that `cat.c` was indeed added to recompiled MINIX):

```
fprintf(stdout, "new line\n");
FILE *fp;
```

Line 157 (line that should print file name):

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", *argv);
filename = *argv++;
```

The problem is that after recompiling (`make build` in `/usr/src`), `cat` does not seem to recognize new `-H` flag. If I type

```
# cat -H .exrc
```

I get

```
cat: unknown option -- H
```

However, if I type

```
# cat -b .exrc

I get
new line
.exrc
1  set autoindent autowrite report=2 showmatch
```

So `cat` has actually changed, as I get "new line" line as well as ".exrc" line (looks like I should have put that inside `if` condition, but anyway), yet `-H` is not recognized.

What have I done wrong? What do I actually have to do to add new flag? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `cat` in Minix uses `getopt`, you also need to add a new option into `getopt` call (which lists all possible options).

The code you have provided doesn't do this. You might also consult `man getopt`.

Comment: This is minix, not linux, the userland is BSDish, so no `getopt_long`. Just `getopt`.

Comment: I had a look at it, but, unfortunately, it did not make things any easier. From what I understood, getopt looks for the letter in optstring. To make -H flag work, I have find this optstring and add 'H' letter there. Am I correct? And if so, in which source file can I find toptstring to modify it?

Comment: @BEEETHvcw your first part is correct, you need to modify optstring. I do not know where minix version of `cat` defines it, you can probably just grep in the repo.

Comment: Oh, I am dumb. All this time it was right in front of my eyes, hidden in plain sight on line 83: while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "beflnstuv")) != -1). I am recompiling MINIX now and hopefully it will work.